# Error adding multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I want to add some attributes to customers, I was able to add one attribute at a time but wanted to add several, but the magento returns me error, what am I doing wrong?

**ERROR:**  `Source model "" not found for attribute "type"`

**mysql4-install.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "type",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Tipo de Cadastro",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "cpf",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "CPF",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "company_name",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Razão Social",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "trading_name",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Nome Fantasia",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "cnpj",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "CNPJ",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "nickname",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Apelido",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "occupation",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Profissão",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "foundation_day",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Data de Fundação da Empresa",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "department",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Departamento",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "how_find_us",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Onde conheceu a Flores Online",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute(
        "customer", "type",
        "customer", "cpf",
        "customer", "company_name",
        "customer", "trading_name",
        "customer", "cnpj",
        "customer", "nickname",
        "customer", "occupation",
        "customer", "foundation_day",
        "customer", "department",
        "customer", "how_find_us");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'type',
    '999',
    'cpf',
    '998',
    'company_name',
    '997',
    'trading_name',
    '996',
    'cnpj',
    '995',
    'nickname',
    '994',
    'occupation',
    '993',
    'foundation_day',
    '992',
    'department',
    '991',
    'how_find_us',
    '990'
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
      $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Teste_Essevai>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Teste_Essevai>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <teste_essevai_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Teste_Essevai</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                </teste_essevai_setup>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute()` and `addAttributeToGroup()` are only meant to work on one attribute at a time. So I'd put the codes in an array and loop through each one, like so:

```
$attributeCodes = array(
    'type'=>999,
    'cpf'=>998,
    'company_name'=>997,
    'trading_name'=>996,
    'cnpj'=>995,
    'nickname'=>994,
    'occupation'=>993,
    'foundation_day'=>992,
    'department'=>991,
    'how_find_us'=>990
);


$used_in_forms=array('adminhtml_customer');

foreach($attributeCodes as $code=>$sort_order) {
    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('customer', $code);
    $setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $attributeGroupId,
        $attribute->getId(),
        $sort_order
    );
    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

Comment: dont work this.

Comment: Hmm. Try removing source then for your attributes. Does it work or give a new error?

Comment: No, I believe it could be in concatenation done in $ attribute

Comment: `getAttribute()` and `addAttributeToGroup()` are only meant to accept one attribute at a time.

Comment: I'd put the codes in an array and iterate through them. For example: `foreach($attribute_codes as $code) { $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(...); $setup->addAttributeToGroup(...); etc... }`

Comment: I'll try to do it this way, could you deploy this in your answer, if right for me to vote it for right?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I'm doing a clean install of the magento and I'll try

Comment: Give the same error, Source model "" not found for attribute "type"

Comment: Strange. Your code works on my Magento installation. I'm running 1.9.3.6. What version are you using (php version too)? Also, can you post your config xml as well?

Comment: Php Version:  4.7.0
Magento Version 1.9.1.1
Question updated with config.xml

Comment: It is creating the categories correctly, but it returns this error ..

Comment: You mean it's creating the attributes correctly? Is the error message something that appears in the logs or something that breaks the site and appears in the browser (or in var/report)?

Comment: Yes, it is something that pops up in the browser when entering customers in the backend, the error by what it seems to be is when pulling the fields to display in the backend

Comment: I found the error, it is in the select type, I did not add the attributes of it

Answer (score 0):

I will post my functional code so that other people can do the same, it creates all the necessary attributes that I need be it text or select. I will also post the code to customer address

**local/your/module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Module>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Module>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <your_module_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Customers_Atributos</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                </your_module_setup>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

**local/your/module/sql/your_module_setup/install.0.1.0.php**

I use this first sql installation just for it to recognize the module in core_resource, I had a problem with that, so if you want to follow the same one so that there are no errors. I do not put anything inside the file, it's just for the magento to recognize the module.

**This is the first file responsible for creating attributes of customers
 local/your/module/sql/your_module_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php**

**Here is an example of each type of input, text and select, if you want to create more than 1 just replicate the field and change what you want, and add the nameattribute in the variable `$attributeCodes`. To do the same with the address table just change the code with the added comments**

```
 <?php
        $installer = $this;
        $installer->startSetup();

        //Follow the comments if you want to add attributes to customers address




        //Change  $installer->addAttribute("customer", "nameattribute", ... to  $installer->addAttribute("customer_address", "nameattribute", 
        $installer->addAttribute("customer", "nameattribute",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Here is the label that will appear",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false)
        );

            $installer->addAttribute("customer", "nameattributeselect",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Here is the label that will appear",
            "input"    => "select",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "source" => "eav/entity_attribute_source_table",
            "option" => array('values' => array('Value 1', 'Value 2')) 
            ));

            $attributeCodes = array(
                'nameattribute',
                'nameattributeselect'
            );


        foreach($attributeCodes as $code) {
        //Change ->getAttribute('customer', $code); to ->getAttribute('customer_address', $code); 
        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('customer', $code);

        //Change array('adminhtml_customer'); to array('adminhtml_customer_address'); 
        $used_in_forms=array('adminhtml_customer');

        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                    ->setData("is_system", 0)
                    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                    ->setData("sort_order", 100);
                $attribute->save();
            }

        $installer->endSetup();
```

**After doing all these steps just change the version of the module in config.xml to the version of the file you created in sql, then just refresh the page of the site, clear the cache and add a new client with its attribute.**